# how to login with ssis package to web service

Tags: ssis

```html
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.DynamicData;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
 namespace ST_977ad26d6e754517ab07c39f6c220cb9
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
         public void Main()
        {
            #region GETRESULTS
            string wUrl = "http://182.301.111.121/crm/customers/new?from_date=20170220&20170221;
             HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(wUrl);
             HttpWebResponse httpWResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
             
            string results="";

                Stream responseStream = httpWResp.GetResponseStream();
                string jsonString = null;

                //Set jsonString using a stream reader
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream) 
                {
                    results = reader.ReadToEnd().ToString();

                    reader.Close();

                }
```

this code is work for other web service but i need to change this code for first login to web service and after login, see data in web service